# Cartthrob Sagepay error

Tags: payment-gateway, expressionengine, payment-processing, cartthrob

Using Sagepay gateway on a build and sorting the gateway integration. Works fine until we get to the actual payment processing and we get the error:

HTTP Status Code:    500
HTTP Status Message:     The request was unsuccessful due to an unexpected condition encountered by the server.
Error Code :     5006
Error Description :  Unable to redirect to Vendor's web site. The Vendor failed to provide a RedirectionURL.

The return url is set on the cartthrob checkout form to return="checkout/order-completed"

I've edited extload.php and modified the settings to match our MSM setup. I've also [asked the guys at CT if they have any guidance](http://cartthrob.com/forums/viewthread/7231/) but figure SO is a good place as well.

Comment: Doesnt the return url need to be a full url? Including http/https and your domain?

Comment: In this case I don't think it does need to be a full URL, what you have is fine, though you may find adding an initial / will help. Is this error being thrown by YOUR server or Sagepay's? I think you might also need to provide an extra parameter in the Payment Processor settings when using SagePay. Which payment plugin are you using? You may actually need to specify the return URL within your SagePay control panel (i.e. not on your site) - from memory there is a fair bit of configuration required at *their* end to use SagePay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies within a file called extload.php which resides within /themes/third_party/cartthrob/lib

As we're using MSM, we had to appropriately map the variables correctly and what we had wrong was the $EE_absolute_server_url where it was an an actual URL when it should have been a server path.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at your Apache error logs to see if there is any more detail listed there?

Also, I had some similar symptoms when mod_evasive was installed on my server and was locked down a little too tight. Might want to try temporarily disabling mod_evasive to test, or at least loosen it up a bit.

This article may help. http://library.linode.com/web-servers/apache/mod-evasive